# How to store postgis datasource in redis (Mapnik)?

Tags: redis, postgis, mapnik

I have built tile server using node-mapnik , so far all good and I am able to render tiles and can be being displayed on front-end.

Now the problem is we have large set of data that is being plotted and lots of filter are being happen on data.  So I am planning to query POSTGIS DB once and store the result set into In memory database like (Redis).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is, a good source to review would be https://github.com/CartoDB/Windshaft which I believe takes a similar approach.

Good luck!

Comment: I have already looked into to this , but the thing is they are caching tile not the data.